Film\TV series with two teams (of students?); One tries mental torture techniques on the other
I remember only this; There was a film or TV series that had two teams (possibly male students?) that were pitted against each other. One team has been given information (a location I believe) and the other team has to get that information from them.
They use sleep deprivation, play with the thermostat and repetitive music to try and get it. One breaks and gives them info but the rest of the team has given him wrong info because they knew he would break.
In the end they get the info because they have put the clock forward and trick the team into giving info before time limit has been reached.
It was either UK/USA. Unsure of year of release, I watched it in the last year or so, so I'm guessing it would be post 2010 but cannot be certain unfortunately.

Approximate year of release? Country\language?

it was either uk/usa .  unsure of year of release, i watched it in the last year or so so i am guessing it would be post 2010 but cannot be certain unfortunately

thank you!!!  been bugging me for a few days- you are correct. i couldn't remember all the binge-watching!

Pretty sure It's the Veronica Mars episode My Big Fat Greek Rush Week (Season 3, Episode 2).

Veronica is hired by the campus newspaper to do an undercover expose on the Zeta Theta sorority sisters during rush week to investigate Parker's rape. Throughout the investigation, Veronica realizes that everything is not exactly what as seems in the sorority house. Meanwhile, Logan and Wallace participate in a prisoner/guard role-playing experiment for their Sociology class, which challenges them psychologically.

They're divided into two teams: prisoners and guards. The prisoners know of the location of a bomb and the guards have 48 hours to extract it. They use sleep deprivation and loud music to torture them. One of the prisoners breaks, but the other prisoners knew that he would and gave him a fake address. In the end, the prisoners think they won and give away the location only to find out that the guards set the clock forward. Can't believe it took me that long to remember this, but it's been a while since I watched the episode (it's from 2006). Here's a relevant clip:



